# Angular multiselect(ss-multiselect-dropdown) positioning

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using ss-multiselect-dropdown 3 times in a component.i need one multiselect dropdown should appear in the top.How i can override the multiselect position .

```html
<ss-multiselect-dropdown id="ss" tabindex="12"  name="site" [options]="mySite" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="siteSettings" [ngModel]="siteOption" (ngModelChange)="onsiteChange($event)" (dropdownOpened)="openChange()" ></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Could you please be more clear and post your code as well?

Comment: It was a simple mistake.i changes the css from component to style.css,that is the main css file in my application